# Not able to run binary executable with sudo. Otherwise runs fine without sudo

Tags: sudo

I have following permissions on file 'App':

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user1 1002 6536757 Dec 26 11:32 App*
```

I am able to run App as below:

```
$./App
```

But when I try with sudo, it reports following error:

```
$sudo ./App
sudo: ./App: command not found
```

I am using Ububtu 12.04 LTS.
App is generated using g++.

I have tried using chmod -R 777 App. Doesn't work still with sudo.

Comment: The App was residing in a remote directory mounted on my system using SSHFS. 

Solution: Use allow_other option of sshfs. Check:
<http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/59685/sshfs-mount-sudo-gets-permission-denied>